# How to calculate the uncertainty of fitting parameter in a nonlinear model

Tags: nonlinear-regression, error, uncertainty

I have a cost function which is:

```
(F(X,B)-Y)*(F(X,B)-Y)
```

`F` is my model, `B` are my fitting parameters, `X` are the independent variables such as time, and `Y` are the experimental data.

After I get the fitting parameters by a minimization algorithm applied on my cost function, how can I get the uncertainty of my fitted parameters `B`? Imagine one of the fitting parameters has the value of 1, how can I get a range around the value of 1 for which the fitting parameter still results in an acceptable minimal loss value? How can I know the range of values that surround the true value of this fitting parameter?

I am new to this area so introducing some learning resources is also appreciated.

Comment: You could [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) your observations and refit your model, many times, then assess the variability of the fitted parameters, or of any function of them.

Comment: So if I understood well, determining the variability or reliability of a fitting parameter comes from the variability of the experimental data? right? I was thinking more of a way to see upon a change in a fitting parameter, how much the loss function changes and this way get an interval over which each fitting parameter is allowed to change without affecting the loss value too much. The issue is I have only one measured data. I have more measured data but each of them are under different conditions and I expect the fitting parameters to be different.

Comment: In other words, I want to know the fitting parameter uncertainty due to the fitting procedure itself and not due to a variability in experimental data. One way would be fitting from different initial points. But assuming I have good initial points I want a way to explore other parameters near the optimal region found by the algorithm in the first time. Will the nearby region yields a comparable loss value? Then the set of all those parameter values which results in a comparable loss value would be my "confidence interval". I do not know how to formulate this.